# Check which IDs from a set do not exists in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of user IDs, like this:

```
757392,733602,749955,744304,746852,753904,755117,636163,564931,740787,751450,743799,643918,
749903,571888,30207,705953,749120,749001,749192,749978,750840,544228,702121,746246,383667,
558790,585628,592771,745818,749375,241209,749235,746860,748318,748016,748951,747321,748684,
748225,565375,748673,747869,748522,748335,744775,672229,578056,713127,740234,632608,711135,
746528,362131,742223,746567,745224,332989,439837,745418,673582,269584,742606,745135,746950,
476134,740830,742949,276934
```

I have a MySQL table `users` with the `id` field.

How do I check - using a query - which IDs of the ones I have **do not** exists in the `users` table?

This sounds like a simple problem to me, yet I couldn't find any example on StackOverflow which would address a fixed set of ID values.

Comment: This is not simple, because SQL does not process string lists very well.

Comment: At least I know why I spent the past hour looking for a solution - and failed. I guess I could create a dummy or temporary table with those IDs and make a LEFT JOIN between the new table and the `users` but this is a chore. Definitely an overkill.

Comment: Use `find_in_set()`.

Comment: Create a temporary table out of this list. Then compare that table with your data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an option:

```
SELECT ids.id
  FROM ( SELECT @i
              , substring(@string, @start, @end-@start) id
            FROM <BigTable>
               , ( SELECT @string := <YourStringOfIds>
                        , @start:=0
                        , @end:=0
                        , @i:=0
                        , @len:=length(@string)
                        , @n:=@len-length(replace(@string,',',''))+1
                 ) t
            WHERE (@i := @i+1) <= @n
              AND (@start := @end+1)
              AND (@loc := locate(',',@string,@start))
              AND @end := if(@loc!=0,@loc,@len+1)
       ) ids
    LEFT JOIN <BigTable> u
      ON u.id = ids.id
  WHERE u.id is null
```

BigTable can be any table whose number of rows >= number of ids in your string.

Comment: This solution is neat and the easiest one to use with a fixed, comma separated list of values. It's also fast (tested on a table with over 300k rows). Anyone interested in how it works should get familiar with [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know the find_in_set() function and took a more handcrafted approach. Not that it makes any sense given the first answer, but I'll post it anyway:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
    SELECT '757392' AS id UNION
    SELECT '733602' UNION
    SELECT '749955' UNION
    SELECT '744304' UNION
    SELECT '746852' UNION
    SELECT '753904' UNION
    SELECT '755117' UNION
    SELECT '636163' UNION
    SELECT '564931' UNION
    SELECT '740787' UNION
    SELECT '751450' UNION
    SELECT '743799' UNION
    SELECT '643918' UNION
    SELECT '749903' UNION
    SELECT '571888' UNION
    SELECT '30207'  UNION   
    SELECT '705953' UNION
    SELECT '749120' UNION
    SELECT '749001' UNION
    SELECT '749192' UNION
    SELECT '749978' UNION
    SELECT '750840' UNION
    SELECT '544228' UNION
    SELECT '702121' UNION
    SELECT '746246' UNION
    SELECT '383667' UNION
    SELECT '558790' UNION
    SELECT '585628' UNION
    SELECT '592771' UNION
    SELECT '745818' UNION
    SELECT '749375' UNION
    SELECT '241209' UNION
    SELECT '749235' UNION
    SELECT '746860' UNION
    SELECT '748318' UNION
    SELECT '748016' UNION
    SELECT '748951' UNION
    SELECT '747321' UNION
    SELECT '748684' UNION
    SELECT '748225' UNION
    SELECT '565375' UNION
    SELECT '748673' UNION
    SELECT '747869' UNION
    SELECT '748522' UNION
    SELECT '748335' UNION
    SELECT '744775' UNION
    SELECT '672229' UNION
    SELECT '578056' UNION
    SELECT '713127' UNION
    SELECT '740234' UNION
    SELECT '632608' UNION
    SELECT '711135' UNION
    SELECT '746528' UNION
    SELECT '362131' UNION
    SELECT '742223' UNION
    SELECT '746567' UNION
    SELECT '745224' UNION
    SELECT '332989' UNION
    SELECT '439837' UNION
    SELECT '745418' UNION
    SELECT '673582' UNION
    SELECT '269584' UNION
    SELECT '742606' UNION
    SELECT '745135' UNION
    SELECT '746950' UNION
    SELECT '476134' UNION
    SELECT '740830' UNION
    SELECT '742949' UNION
    SELECT '276934') AS id_list
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM users);
```

Comment: Nice. This one **works** as well. A bit cumbersome to build, but doable.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [IN clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) with a negation. I.e. you can specify your list as the argument to the IN clause like so:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE id NOT IN ( 757392,733602,749955,744304,746852,753904,755117,636163,564931,740787,751450,743799,643918,749903,571888,30207,705953,749120,749001,749192,749978,750840,544228,702121,746246,383667,558790,585628,592771,745818,749375,241209,749235,746860,748318,748016,748951,747321,748684,748225,565375,748673,747869,748522,748335,744775,672229,578056,713127,740234,632608,711135,746528,362131,742223,746567,745224,332989,439837,745418,673582,269584,742606,745135,746950,476134,740830,742949,276934 );
```

## UPDATE

My bad - I didn't read the question properly.
So the correct way would be to go with `UNION`s then outer join and filter by `NULL`, like this:

```
SELECT WantedIds.id
FROM users
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT x.id
        FROM (
            SELECT '757392' AS id UNION
            SELECT '733602' UNION
            SELECT '749955' UNION
            SELECT '744304' UNION
            SELECT '746852' UNION
            SELECT '753904' UNION
            SELECT '755117' UNION
            SELECT '636163' UNION
            SELECT '564931' UNION
            .
            .
            .
        ) x
    ) WantedIds
    ON WantedIds.id = users.id
WHERE users.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Create temporary table, then fill it

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO tmp (id) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)
```

then make a query

```
SELECT tmp.id
FROM tmp 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = tmp.id
WHERE tmp.id IS NULL
```

finally drop the table

```
DROP TABLE tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [find_in_set() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to check if a value exists in a commase separated list of values:

```
select * from your_table
where find_in_set(field_name,'757392,733602,749955,744304,746852,753904,755117,636163,564931,740787,751450')=0
```

Comment: Looks neat but, unfortunately, it gives me **all** the rows in the table `users`. I even tried to add some dummy IDs to the set. Also, I don't understand how this is supposed to work. What I need is the ID (from the given set) which *cannot* be found in the table. So, your query seems to try to `select` something that *shouldn't be there*. Am I getting this wrong?